# How to add custom command to cheatsheet in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to add a custom command to my cheat sheet, I had make it work well, except when open the plugin.xml with Plug-in Manifest Editor, there is an error.

**Here are the steps I used to implement the function:**

1: Define custom command in plugin.xml.

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <category
        id="com.ting.commands.category"
        name="Custom Category">
  </category>
  <command
        categoryId="com.ting.commands.category"
        defaultHandler="com.ting.commands.ExampleCommandHandler"
        description="Example Command"
        id="com.ting.commands.exampleCommand"
        name="Custom commands">
  </command>
```

2: Add command to cheat sheet item.

```xml
 <item
      title="Example cheat sheet item">
   <description>
   Example item description
   </description>
   <command
         required="false"
         serialization="com.ting.commands.exampleCommand"/>
</item>
```

**Error message:**

```
Message : Failed to deserialize command: com.ting.commands.ExampleCommandHandler
```

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.common.NotDefinedException: Cannot get the parameters from an undefined command. com.ting.commands.ExampleCommandHandler
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.getParameters(Command.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager.deserialize(CommandManager.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.commands.CommandService.deserialize(CommandService.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ua.ui.editor.cheatsheet.simple.details.SimpleCSCommandDetails.getParameterizedCommand(SimpleCSCommandDetails.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ua.ui.editor.cheatsheet.simple.details.SimpleCSCommandDetails.getParameterizedCommand(SimpleCSCommandDetails.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ua.ui.editor.cheatsheet.simple.details.SimpleCSCommandDetails.updateFields(SimpleCSCommandDetails.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ua.ui.editor.cheatsheet.simple.details.SimpleCSItemDetails.updateFields(SimpleCSItemDetails.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ua.ui.editor.cheatsheet.simple.details.SimpleCSItemDetails.selectionChanged(SimpleCSItemDetails.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.DetailsPart$1.run(DetailsPart.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.DetailsPart.showPage(DetailsPart.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.DetailsPart.update(DetailsPart.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.DetailsPart.selectionChanged(DetailsPart.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.ManagedForm.fireSelectionChanged(ManagedForm.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.TreeSection$PartAdapter.selectionChanged(TreeSection.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.parts.TreePart$1.selectionChanged(TreePart.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2132)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1124)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ua.ui.editor.cheatsheet.simple.SimpleCSMasterTreeSection.setFormInput(SimpleCSMasterTreeSection.java:1233)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ua.ui.editor.cheatsheet.simple.SimpleCSDefinitionPage.setActive(SimpleCSDefinitionPage.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.pageChange(FormEditor.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.PDEFormEditor.pageChange(PDEFormEditor.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1200)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1025)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:2045)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3493)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1287)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you specified the correct command serialization in you example? From the error message it looks like you specified `com.ting.commands.ExampleCommandHandler` rather than `com.ting.commands.exampleCommand` for the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I assume (Cheat Sheet?) editor can't find the command because the defining plugin is not part of your target platform. If you export the plugin and add to your development platform, it should work fine.